# make a single call to a pipe in the same item

Tags: angular

I'm new to this topic of `pipes`.

I have a question, I am trying to make a condition to decide the style that will have a label to create `badges`.

```
<mdb-badge [success]="(item.eve_fecha | fechahumana).tiempo.dias>=3" [warning]="(item.eve_fecha | fechahumana).tiempo.dias<2"  >{{(item.eve_fecha | fechahumana).mensaje}}</mdb-badge>
```

my problem is that this `pipe` is called 3 times, 2 times for the conditions that I do to assign the style

```
[success]="(item.eve_fecha | fechahumana).tiempo.dias>=3"  x1
[warning]="(item.eve_fecha | fechahumana).tiempo.dias<2"   x2
```

and 1 additional for showing the value of the `badge`.

```
{{(item.eve_fecha | fechahumana).mensaje}} x3
```

How can I make a single call to the `pipe`?

my pipe returns:

```
.
.
.
{"mensaje":string,"tiempo":object};
```

Inside my pipe I perform a little heavy operations so I do not want the same calculation to be done so many times.

Comment: What type of value is `item.eve_fecha`?

Comment: item.eve_fecha is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [memoize](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-memoize-in-javascript-51d07d19430e) the pipe `transform` function, so that it doesn't have to perform the heavy operations again if the result is known for a given input value:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'fechahumana' })
export class FechahumanaPipe implements PipeTransform {

  private cache = new Map<string, Object>();

  transform(value: string): Object {
    if (!this.cache.has(value)) {
      this.cache.set(value, this.calcTransformedValue(value));
    }
    return this.cache.get(value);
  }

  calcTransformedValue(value: string): Object {
    // Perform the heavy operations here
    // return the transformed value
  }

}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jybwwr?file=app%2Ffechahumana-pipe.ts) for a demo.

Comment: thanks! is this a good practice?  for what is? [attr.data-v1] [attr.data-v2]..?

Comment: I used the `data-v1`, `data-v2` attributes to show that various attributes can be set on the same element, with the same transformed value (I was too lazy to create a custom component with input values). Memoizing is a good practice to avoid repeating lengthy operations as you can read in [the linked article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-memoize-in-javascript-51d07d19430e).

Comment: Is it possible to use [data-v1] and use <>{{div1.data-v1}} </> instead of the memoize?

Comment: I am getting an error with <h3>Memoized</h3>
<div #div1 *ngFor="let item of items" [attr.data-v1]="item | fechahumana" [hidden]="!div1.dataset.v1==0" >
{{div1.dataset.v1}}
</div>     : Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'hidden: false'. Current value: 'hidden: true'.

Comment: The memoizing is not related to using data attributes like `data-v1`. I added an example to [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jybwwr?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) where the pipe is applied to the `[title]` (tooltip) property of the elements. As for the exception, I don't see this `[hidden]` binding in your original question; this is a new requirement.

Comment: he asked more out of curiosity than for a new requirement. I was trying to use the binding with [hidden] capturing the value of fechahumana without using the memoize, that was my doubt